# Is white winning in chess with the 1st and 8th ranks reversed?

Tags: analysis, theory, chess-variants

Here is the position I am referring to:

```
[FEN "RNBQKBNR/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/rnbqkbnr w - - 0 1"]
```

It seems that there are no forced checkmates for white, any f3-Qh4# plans are thwarted by the black queen simply capturing one of the pawns and making an escape square for the king on e1. The evaluation of Stockfish 15 is also indecisive at +1 after 5 billion nodes.

Comment: Sideline: If you reverse the officers too, the position seems to be won big time for white (Lichess Stockfish +8 on depth 30 after 1.Na6).

Comment: I don't get the "f3-Qh4# plans" remark since the black King has escape squares by capturing on d2 or e2.

Comment: This is surprisingly a very difficult question to answer. I analysed this position a few days ago, and there seemed to be multiple lines somewhere in the +1s. This is the worst possible evaluation for "proving" a win or draw, since such evaluations in the ballpark of +1 can be either objective wins or draws.